# Python GCS how to rename file within inner zip file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Suppose I have a file hosted on GCS on a Python AppEngine project. unfortunately, this file structure is something like:

```
outer.zip/
  - inner.zip/
    - vid_file
    - png_file
```

the problem is that the two files inside `inner.zip` do not have the `.mp4` extension on the file, and it's causing all sorts of troubles. How do i rename the files so that it appears like:

```
outer.zip/
  - inner.zip/
    - vid_file.mp4
    - png_file.png
```

so that the files inside `inner.zip` have their extensions?

I keep running into all sorts of limitations since `gcs` doesn't allow file renaming, unarchiving...etc.

the files aren't terribly large.

P.S. i'm not very familiar with Python, so any code examples would be great appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely **no** way to perform **any** alteration to GCS objects -- full stop.  They are exactly the bunch of bytes you decided at their birth (uninterpreted by GCS itself) and thus they will stay.

The best you can do is create a **new** object which is almost like the original except it fixes little errors and oopses you did when creating the original.  Then you can overwrite (i.e completely replace) the original with the new, improved version.

Hopefully it's a one-off terrible mistake you made just once and now want to fix so it's not worth writing a program for that.  Just download that GCS object, use normal tools to unzip it and unzip any further zipfiles it may contain, do the fixes on the filesystem with your favorite local filesystem tools, zip things up again, upload/rewrite the final zip to your desired new GCS object -- phew, you're done.

Comment: -> that's just the problem though. the original content ONLY comes in via a zip file. while i can certainly do a cron job on my local server using gsutil to re-create the files with proper extensions, it then won't be instantaneous.

Comment: also, i don't mind creating a separate zip file (the copy of original, but with correct file extensions), and then deleting the original zip file. However, i can't seem to find a way to create a zipfile from zip output stream and continuously add files to it

Comment: No idea what you mean by "comes in via a zip file" -- is there a server creating this GCS object repeatedly and always wrong?  Then show us the server code if you can fix it and we'll show how; clearly, fixing the badly-buggy server is the only right approach. If not, if it's not a programming Q, then it's not a stackoverflow problem.  If the broken zipfile is there as a one-off job as your Q still implies, then my advice applies: download the gcs object, etc, etc, as I already answered.

Comment: @DavidT. again you lose me: where in your Q is there anything about "**continuously** add files"?!  **Please** look hard and deep at your Q and edit it so it provides **all** information (100%, **not** 99.9%!-) to the poor people who are trying to help you -- please don't make the job of helping you as hard as you possibly can, which seems to be what you're successfully attempting!  "I have a file" for example is many parsecs away from "continuously add files" as you now pull out of the blue -- totally mysterious potential implications in your text keep assaulting me.  PLEASE fix the Q!!!

Comment: okay. i ended up fixing it on the server side. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Alex is right that objects are immutable, i.e., no editing in-place. The only way to accomplish what you're talking about would be to download the current file, unzip it, update the new files, re-zip the files into the same-named file, and upload to GCS. GCS object overwrites are transactional, so the old content will be visible until the instant the upload completes. Doing it this way is obviously not very network efficient but at least it wouldn't leave periods of time when the object is invisible (as deleting and re-uploading would).

Answer (score 0):

"Import zipfile" and you can unzip the file once it's downloaded into gcs storage.
I have code doing exactly this on a nightly basis from a cron job.
Ive never tried creating a zip file with GAE but the docs say you can do it.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html